# Can changing from datetime to datetime2 ever cause bugs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, jdbc

My team would like to update our SQL Server `datetime` columns (which only have 3 digits of precision with weird rounding rules) to use `datetime2` with 7 digit precision.

Are there any well known edge cases where this kind of change would cause a problem or require modifying business logic that uses those dates?

We use Java so any low level interpretation would be handled by the driver jar. I just can't think of a situation when having *more* precision would be a bad thing (storage space is not an issue), but these changes make some people nervous, and if I had a dollar for every time I had to fix a bug I couldn't think of ahead of time I'd be rich.

[edited to add: we would also update all stored procedures to use `datetime2` instead of `datetime` for all variables and temp tables, so you wouldn't have e.g. a temp table created with `datetime` that would store `datetime2` values].

Comment: Why not try it on a test environment and see what happens (as a PoC)? (Write a proper test plan and all as well should the initial deployment/change work as expected). Hard to know anything else without seeing code...

Comment: Do you need 7 digits? Or just 3?

Comment: I guess I'm wondering what situations to consider or look for when making a test plan.

Comment: Probably don't need 7, and we could push back on that, but that's part of why I'm wondering, what's the harm? Plus I'm also curious about just switching from `datetime` to `datetime2`, which as @HoneyBadger noted below, can be a problem itself in some situations even if precision is the same.

Comment: It can have significant impact on existing code. Read [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/de5dbf3e-8c95-40f4-9e31-b71f1f31983d/change-in-datetime2-implementation-in-sql-server-2016?forum=transactsql)

Answer (score 6):

One thing that pops into my head is this:

```
DECLARE @test DATETIME = '20100101'

SELECT  @test
,       @test - 1
```

Try and replace it with `DATETIME2`

Answer (score 2):

Here's something I found:

```sql
DECLARE @dt DATETIME = SYSDATETIME()
DECLARE @dt2 DATETIME2(7) = SYSDATETIME()
DECLARE @str char(27) = @dt
DECLARE @str2 char(27) = @dt2
SELECT @str, ISDATE(@str), @str2, ISDATE(@str2)
```

Prints `Aug 27 2019 10:22AM`, `1`, `2019-08-27 10:22:25.9935078`, `0`

Two things going on:

1. `datetime` and `datetime2` convert to `char` in different formats.
2. `ISDATE()` returns false when there are more than 3 digits of precision.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of increasing precision, if you have code such as the following which is designed specifically for `datetime`:

```
WHERE dtcol BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31 23:59:59.997' -- all Jan 2019 datetime values
```

Then it must be changed to:

```
WHERE dtcol BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31 23:59:59.9999999'
/*
 * inside the literal, the number of nines after decimal must be
 * equal to/greater than the fractional precision of the column
 * e.g. the datetime2(3) value '2019-01-31 23:59:59.999'
 * <= '2019-01-31 23:59:59.9999' is true
 * <= '2019-01-31 23:59:59.999' is true
 * <= '2019-01-31 23:59:59.99' is false
 *
 */
```

Or better:

```
WHERE dtcol >= '2019-01-01'
  AND dtcol <  '2019-02-01' -- now the comparison is independent of datatype and precision
```

---

As for datatype change, be aware of the following constructs (*tricks*) hidden inside your code:

#### `SELECT dtcol + 1`

While this adds 1 day to a datetime value, this code simply fails on datetime2 datatype. Use `DATEADD` function instead.

#### `SELECT DATEADD(..., DATEDIFF(..., 0, dtcol), 0)`

This is often used to zero-out month/day/hour/minute/etc part of a datetime like so:

```
SELECT dtcol                                        -- 2019-08-27 16:17:18.123
     , DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, dtcol), 0) -- 2019-08-01 00:00:00.000
     , DATEADD(DAY,   DATEDIFF(DAY,   0, dtcol), 0) -- 2019-08-27 00:00:00.000
     , DATEADD(HOUR,  DATEDIFF(HOUR,  0, dtcol), 0) -- 2019-08-27 16:00:00.000
```

The 0s in the above example are assumed to be a datetime value of `1753-01-01` resulting in conversions from datetime2 to datetime and the return type is datetime.

Use `DATETIME2FROMPARTS` instead for such purpose or rewrite the code as follows:

```
SELECT dtcol                                                                                    -- 2019-08-27 16:17:18.12345
     , DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '0001-01-01', dtcol), CAST('0001-01-01' AS DATETIME2(5))) -- 2019-08-01 00:00:00.00000
     , DATEADD(DAY,   DATEDIFF(DAY,   '0001-01-01', dtcol), CAST('0001-01-01' AS DATETIME2(5))) -- 2019-08-27 00:00:00.00000
     , DATEADD(HOUR,  DATEDIFF(HOUR,  '0001-01-01', dtcol), CAST('0001-01-01' AS DATETIME2(5))) -- 2019-08-27 16:00:00.00000
```